# Can not restore solarized dark theme after updating all packages via MELPA

Tags: themes, package-repositories, upgrade

I updated all my packages via MELPA today and I previously had a solarized dark theme and now its solarized light. I did not change my init.el or any settings. Emacs is not showing any errors. Wondering what the issue likely is and how can I restore the theme?

I have posted this as an issue on : https://github.com/bbatsov/solarized-emacs/issues/167

Comment: Restarting Emacs or using `M-x load-theme RET solarized-dark RET` should do the trick. Also, please mention https://github.com/bbatsov/solarized-emacs/issues/167 assuming that's your issue.

Comment: So you're saying that you have a bunch of undescribed stuff that you updated, and one of those updates changed something. And you are asking what to do to get back the behavior before all of your updates. Have you tried a fortune teller? If @wasamasa didn't guess correctly then try narrowing things down in your init file and letting us know specifically what code is involved?

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed the theme from https://github.com/sellout/emacs-color-theme-solarized with package name that begins with color-theme-solarized, then I have noticed random changes also.

I reinstalled the theme from https://github.com/bbatsov/solarized-emacs with package name solarized-theme, then everything went back to normal.

Hope this helps.